# Non sticky service starts itself and crashes

Tags: android, android-service

My service class code:
I am using  `android.app.Service`

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
         // some work
       stopService(intent);
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind: ");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

I start it by:

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ServiceClass.class));
```

When I run this it executes once properly. But then it tries to start again and crashes with the following error.

```
 ANR in com.sample.service
    PID: 7381
    Reason: executing service com.sample.service/.ServiceClass
    Load: 0.93 / 0.73 / 0.82
    CPU usage from 59831ms to 0ms ago (2018-11-15 13:26:46.668 to 2018-11-15 13:27:46.500):
      13% 1810/system_server: 8.7% user + 4.5% kernel / faults: 12123 minor
```

`stopSelf();` gives the same error. I have no pending intents no broadcast receivers, the service is registered in the manifest. the work part is a forloop counting from 1 to 100 with the current thread sleeping `Thread.sleep(100);`. Please don't recommend alternatives, I have a jobscheduler doing this same work and I just wanted to learn Services.

Comment: What makes you believe this is happening because "it starts itself again"?

Comment: the reason in the error says so.

Comment: no, it says "executing service" which doesn't mean it started itself another time

Comment: what kind of work are you doing in the onStartCommand?

Comment: just a for loop counting from 1 to 100. I delay the thread with Thread.sleep(1000). So what does "executing service" mean?

Comment: Services run on the UI thread. Your 100x sleep() is causing the ANR

Comment: hold on I'll remove it and see.

Comment: try removing the @Nullable tag over onBind()

Comment: yeah seems okay when I removed it. It did crash once when I set the loop limit to 2000 with no delay... so how do I run it on a different thread.. will starting a new thread work??

Comment: @SayokMajumder ok I will try.

Comment: it did work guys I put the loop inside a new Thread and removed the nullable over onBind. @SayokMajumder I this is a unbounded service how does onBind fit into this ?

Comment: The onBind() method has to be written what ever the service may be, but to make it unbounded you only need to return null and to make it bounded you have to return Ibinder object. Android might be checking for the onBind() and @Nullable makes android think that onBind is not written ie it is null and thus throwing exception.

Comment: ok thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You're getting ANR since onStartCommand is on UI thread. Just use [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService) or [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService) (if you don't care about exact time of launch and you want to make it works on Oreo with new limitations) for this kind of jobs.

Comment: timing is important here.What if I do the work in a new Thread?

Comment: IntentService = HandlerThread + Service, so just use IntentService. Also IntentService make some works in onHandleIntent and will make stopself after that. Just check IntentService source it's pretty simple. Don't orget that u will have problems on Oreo devices, cuz of limitations (so there are bunch of options to avoid this limitations: 1) make startForegroundService, but user will see notification that your service is running and doing some kind of job (simplest solution), 2) JobService (JonIntentService), 3) WorkManager)